# Encode video into *.F4V file with h.264 video and AAC+V2 / HE-AAC audio

Tags: video-conversion, video-encoding, multimedia, flash-video

I need to encode a video into a *.F4V file with h.264 video and AAC+V2 / HE-AAC audio.

I seriously doubt that any free software can do that, especially the audio codec which is patented. The only capable program know is Adobe Media Encoder, but it is not standalone app, it comes with whole suite of things I do not really need.

Is there any standalone tool that does precisely that and nothing more?

Comment: yes, that what I mean

Comment: Good question, actually. The audio is kind of a problem indeed. I don't know anything by heart, nor have I ever found something apart from Adobe Media Encoder.